# Google Analytics ga:date returns different in ga:hour

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Everytime I call on ga:date with a ga:adClicks metrics, it returns a non zero values, but when I changed the dimension into ga:hour, it returns a zero value.

Here is the screenshot:

**ga:date as the metrics, it returns a non zero value in the adClicks column**
[image]

**ga:hour as the metrics, it returns zero value.**
[image]

I was thinking that it should result a non zero value because the start date and the end date is just the same. When the dimension has been changed into ga:hour, it should result a total of 21, which in this case it does not.

Am I missing something here? Any tips. Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's weird, my guess is they don't have the data for hour associated with adclicks.  Going to email someone will let you know if I hear anything back.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you very much! This is not only happening to adClicks, this is also happening to some other metrics. Please do email me if that someone already answered you. Thanks again! :)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets  If you select adClicks you will notice that you cant then select ga:minute i suspect that they forgot to add ga:hour to the you cant mix that dimension.  I don't think they have time for ga:adclicks.  The same thing happends on the website you get 0 back

Comment: @DaImTo Hmm, not sure what you mean by that. That's definitely weird.

Comment: Basically there are some dimensions and metrics that cant be mixed because Either it doesn't make sense to mix them or because Google doesn't have the data needed to associate them.   IMO Google Doesn't have the information on what time an add was clicked so it cant give it to you.  I have contacted a couple of the devs but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: @DalmTo I understand it now. Yeah, maybe google really doesn't know those data yet that's why they don't offer such response. Though this is also happening other than adclicks. Hopefully we can hear from other devs on this. Lemme know though. Thanks! :)